# How to enable and disable ckeditor inline toolbar in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have 3 contenteditable divs in on page. I need one of them to have inline ckeditor toolbar. But when I use the following lines in code in order to hide ckeditor toolbar, ckeditor is disabled for all of them. If I enable the inline editing all of the divs have the ckeditor toolbar.

```
     // disable inline editing of ckeditor.
     CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

It can be solve by using inline() method of CKEditor.

For example, there are 3 editable divs (ids are div1, div2, div3). I just want  div2 with inline toolbar. The could would look like,

```
   <div id = "div1" contenteditable></div>
   <div id = "div2" contenteditable></div>
   <div id = "div3" contenteditable></div>


   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
           CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
           CKEDITOR.inline( 'div2');
           });
```